# Using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet save large file result in 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using the following to save and download Excel files in PHP.

```
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

It used to be ok, but recently when the records reach 6k rows, I get a 504 gateway time-out message. I did increase the `max_execution_time` in php.ini, but still get the error message.

```
function downloadExcel($titles = [], $datas = [], $fileName = 'simple')
{
    $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->fromArray(
            $titles,  // The data to set
            NULL,     // Array values with this value will not be set
            'A1'      // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
            // we want to set these values (default is A1)
        );


    $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->fromArray(
            $datas,  // The data to set
            NULL,    // Array values with this value will not be set
            'A2'     // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
            // we want to set these values (default is A1)
        );

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Xlsx)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($this->spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to avoid this? Sounds like a scenario where you should generate the file in a seperate process that is not bound to a HTTP call

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried split the records to two sheet in same Excel file, but still failed. Then I tried just save to local server but not work.

Comment: The right way to do this is as @Nico Hasse says. Create a way to store file generation requests, queue them so that a worker can dequeue and process the requests, and update the request record with the file generation status. You can regularly check the status using AJAX and allow the user to download the file when it is ready.

Comment: It might also be the case that gathering the data for that spreadsheet is too slow, but as you haven't shared any details about where that data comes from, this is pure speculation

Comment: @NicoHaase and RobRuchte Thanks for the reply. The data is come from database, for gathering the data it just take less than 20 seconds. I'll try using worker to generate the file, too.
But the weird thing is it just cost 1min to generate the file and can start to download from browser when records is about 5k rows. When reaching 6k rows, it start to failed...

Comment: typo: 50k rows and 60k rows.

Comment: I've had issues with XLSX files taking large amounts of memory for simple but many-rowed data conversions. I would interpret what's happening here as a memory concern related to creating the XLSX file itself (in memory).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the AWS load balance has set the timeout for the script execution...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html

After changing the Idle timeout to 180 seconds, I can keep running download process.

Sorry for not mention the server environment, and thanks for all your help.

And Thanks my friend Liz for helping me find out this solution.